# Can I use delayer element inside a chain?

Tags: spring-integration

I have the following configuration:

```
<jms:inbound-gateway request-channel="requestChannel"
                     request-destination="requestQueue"
                     default-reply-destination="replyQueue"
                     connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>

<chain input-channel="requestChannel">
   <transformer ref="xmlTransformer" method="fromXml"/>
   <service-activator ref="myService" method="service"/>
   <transformer ref="xmlTransformer" method="toXml"/>
   <!--<delayer id="replyDelayer" default-delay="1000"/>--> 
</chain>
```

I want to delay the reply for debugging purpose.

Without a delayer the configuration works fine. When I add a delayer, the replay does not get to the reply destination.

Is it an incorrect usage of delayer? I don't get any xsd warnings with this configuration.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested this case and it works well for me.

Several point to consider:

- `<jms:inbound-gateway>` uses `receiveTimeout = 5000` by default. However I see that your `<delayer>` delays just for `1000`. So, should be enough
- If your delayer uses persistent `MessageStore` you should use:

  ```
  <int:header-enricher>
      <int:header-channels-to-string />
  </int:header-enricher>
  ```

  to store `replyChannel` header to the DB as well. and restore it from the `delay task`.

Otherwise share, please, StackTrace on the matter.

Comment: I do not configure any messageStore for the delayer. I have only two attributes in the delayer element: default-delay and id. May be this issue is not reproduced on the latest version. I use spring-integration 2.2.4

Comment: 1. Would be better to upgrade at least to the latest ` 3.0.6`. 2. Try to do the same, but when `<delayer>` is out of `<chain>`